# NSIS: Invalid command: ${GetTime}

Tags: nsis

I followed the example in [NSIS manual for `${GetTime}`](http://omega.idv.tw/nsis/SectionE.1.html#E.1.6)

```
${GetTime} "" "LS" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
```

but it causes a compile error

```
Invalid command: ${GetTime}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put the following somewhere before calling `${GetTime}`

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!insertmacro GetTime
```

taken from http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=268160#post2157957